Understanding redirect handling in JFrog Artifactory
I would like to understand how redirect handling is managed in JFrog Artifactory. There seem to be multiple layers involved such as:

Ingress Controller in Kubernetes
Built-in Apache configuration that is part of Artifactory
Configuration of Helm chart to provide additional value overwrites

Does Artifactory store the redirect details in the URL or does it use a different mechanism like cookies, local storage, etc. to handle the redirect. For all URLs that I have inspected via the development console in my browser I could not find any occurence of a ?redirect query parameter.
My main issue is that when I navigate to a protected resource I just get to the login screen. There are not responses with 401 or 30x status codes in the traffic. Every request produces a 200 OK and the first request that I make to the protected resource seems to contain some basic Artifactory HTML document that then triggers follow-up requests via Javascript.
Since deep-linking and redirection is such a basic feature, I cannot imaging that Artifactory does not support this and I think there must be a configuration error either in my Helm Chart configuration, in my ingress controller or somewhere in Artifactory itself.
Where do I start debugging this?
